# How do you pronounce Calvin in British English

Tags: pronunciation, british-english

How do the British pronounce the 'a' between **c** and **l**? Is it like 'callous' or 'call'?

Answer (score 3):

For the name Calvin, it's like the a sound in 'callous'. I've never heard any British person pronounce it the other way.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your options are

/a/ as in 'cat',

/ɑː/ as in 'car',

/ɔː/ as in 'call'.

I reckon most UK speakers would say the first.  I'd expect the second could easily be found in some dialects (e.g. Northern Ireland ?).  The third seems unlikely anywhere, but I don't know.